# Replace character with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="rate-number-up-down-rating positive">+1</div>
```

I am trying to remove the `+` sign. After searching I came to the following code:

```
v = $("div.rate-number-up-down-rating").html().replace(/[+]/g, ""));
$("div.rate-number-up-down-rating").html(v);
```

But it is not working. What am I missing here? Maybe because it is a plus sign?

Comment: Did you notice the syntax error in the Javascript console?

Comment: I would suggest against the /[+]/ in favor of /\+/, I don't like when special characters are not treated like so

Comment: There's no accounting for taste

Answer (score 3):

You have a stray closing parenthesis. That's a syntax error.

```
v = $("div.rate-number-up-down-rating").html().replace(/[+]/g, ""));
                                                               ---^---
```

This should have appeared in your JavaScript console. It always a good thing checking it for errors.